# How to use python to access server through MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: python, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm testing my web server by running it locally through MS VSWD 2010 Express. I need to use python to access a database and add data to it. I was wondering how I can do this. I've tried doing so with packages such as pyodbc and sqlite3 and have had errors when attempting to connect.

I'm specifically wondering if I have to do anything in particular because my server is running through MS VS:WD.

Thanks,

Parth

Comment: Do you mean you're using the builtin development server of Visual Web Developer?

Comment: I mean that I have a server that I'm debugging in Visual Studio, and I want to use a python script to add data to that database. This is a test before I run the script on a production server

Comment: Can you explain how you're debugging a server through Visual Studio? Generally to use the debugger, you attach to a process such as the web server, but Visual Studio is actually watching for break points in the code that is running on the server, not for anything that is happening with the server itself.

Comment: I'm running a web server locally through Visual Studio. So I have all the contents of it saved into a directory and I"m opening it via visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Python on .NET is possible using [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/):

> IronPython is an open-source implementation of the Python programming
>   language which is tightly integrated with the .NET Framework.
>   IronPython can use the .NET Framework and Python libraries, and other
>   .NET languages can use Python code just as easily.